# Facebook sharer wrong data in post

Tags: facebook, caching

I am using the facebook sharer URL to share a website. I have filled in all the meta tags in my header, and when I check the Facebook's debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), I get the correct data as an example. Whenever I click the link below the example (See this in the share dialog.), I still get old information.

The information it shows is the reserved domainpage from the domain registrar. However, I changed its DNS to my VPS, and the website is up and running now. I have tried the ?fbrefresh parameter, but nothing seems to work.

It is weird that the 'debugger' shows the right information, and the live URL is showing the old.

It is about this URL: http://gotony.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked the "Fetch new scrape information" button for you and voila, there you go.

Facebook will always use the cached version for display unless you request an explicit cache update via an app or the refresh button in the debugger. Besides these manual actions Facebook will update it's cache every 30 days for existing URLs.

Comment: Hey Lars, it's pretty weird, it is, indeed, working right now. However, yesterday I fetched new data a couple times on the facebook page, and it did show me the right data as I described. However, in the share dialog, it still showed the old data. No idea why it is working now. Thanks for the magic click!